# Given a smooth 2-form $\varphi$ on a punctured Riemann surface, is there $\nu$ of type (1,0) such that $\varphi=d\nu$?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hodge-theory, differential-forms

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface, $p\in X$, and $\varphi$ be a smooth 2-form on a $X-\{p\}$, and hence exact. I'm wondering if it is possible to find a form of type (1,0) whose differential is $\varphi$. I know that for example if $\varphi$ is smooth and non-exact on $X$, this is always possible using Green functions.

I know this is very basic and not really research level, but I need it for something to work, and unfortunately cannot find a reference for it. Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A punctured surface is affine, hence the $\bar\partial$-complexes are acyclic, hence "yes".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein_manifold#Non-compact_Riemann_surfaces_are_Stein.  It is better to ask questions which you know are "not research level" over at math.stackexchange.  Many of the same people hang out at both sites, but this partitioning of resources makes both sites function better.